# Angular 10 file download

Tags: angular

service with this function to recive the data

```
  import { RequestOptions, ResponseContentType, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    downloadFile(id): Observable<Blob> {
        let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + `coursepurchased/receipt/` + bookingId, options)
        .pipe(map(res => res.blob()))
    }
```

component parse the blob with 'file-saver'

```
import {saveAs as importedSaveAs} from "file-saver";
 getCourseReceipt(bookingId) {
    this.studentInfoService.getCourseInvoice(bookingId).subscribe(
      blob => {
        var fileName = 'test.pdf';
        importedSaveAs(blob, fileName)
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.alertService.showAlert(error.message, "error");
      }
    );
  }
```

This is my angular 6 version download code ..after i have updgraded to 10 RequestOptions deprecated/

Please help me alternative solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the get method for (taken from `http.d.ts`):

```
get<T>(url: string, options?: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<T>;
```

So you can do the following:

```
downloadFile(id): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + `coursepurchased/receipt/` + bookingId, { responseType: "blob" });
}
```

and the component should look like:

```
getCourseReceipt(bookingId) {
    this.studentInfoService.getCourseInvoice(bookingId).subscribe(
      response => {
        var fileName = 'test.pdf';
        let blob:any = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8' });
        importedSaveAs(blob, fileName)
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.alertService.showAlert(error.message, "error");
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: you dont need to write it anywhere, just replace the single line for `this.http.get` with the second block I wrote, the first block quote is from the documentation for http.get method

Comment: am little confused can u pls update downloadFile() in the answer..

Comment: downloadFile(id: number) {      
           
      this.httpClient.get(baseUrl + '/Transaction/DownloadFile?id=' + `${id}` , { responseType: "blob" })
      
  }
Is this coorect?